# Need help with an equation, please.

Tags: integration

Please help.
Don't know how to solve it :(

> $$\begin{align*}
> J=&\int_{AB}xy\,ds\\\\
> AB:\;&\begin{cases}x=\cos t\\y=\sin t\end{cases}\qquad t\in[0,\pi/2]\quad A=(1;0)\quad B=(0;1)
> \end{align*}$$

([Original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1MJ2.jpg).)

Comment: If you can't take the time to type it up, why should people click through?  Please see the help page about how to ask questions here.

Comment: Unclear what $ds$ is, to me. Overall, it looks like a compendium of bad notations.

Comment: This is not an equation

Comment: I was wondering myself if it was an equation. ds is something strange.

Comment: This is probably a line integral around the unit circle; where $ds^{2}=dx^{2}+dy^{2}=1dt^{2}$.

Comment: But how should I solve it? It is so strange, I haven't seen anything like this before (AB under the integral for example)

Comment: @G.Sassatelli, I think $ds$ is typically $ds = \sqrt{\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)^2} \, dt$.

Comment: Please see here for $\LaTeX$ tutorial: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$AB$ is just the name of a set.  Specifically, it's the set of all points $(\cos t, \sin t)$, where $t$ ranges from $0$ to $\pi/2$.  In set builder notation it'd be  $$AB = \{ (\cos t, \sin t) \colon t \in [0,\pi/2] \}$$

Why it's called $AB$, and not maybe just $A$ (or some other one-letter name), is a mystery to me, but oh well.  I guess it's because of those points $A(1,0)$ and $B(0,1)$, but I don't find those to be relevant or useful (or standardly written) pieces of info.  Meh.

Anyway, we also have $$ ds = \sqrt{\dot{x}^2 + \dot{y}^2} \, dt = \sqrt{(-\sin t)^2 + (\cos t)^2} \, dt = 1 \, dt = dt$$

So the integral becomes $$ \int_0^{\pi/2} \underbrace{\cos t}_{x} \cdot \underbrace{\sin t}_{y} \, \underbrace{dt}_{ds}$$